# Dishes have pointers to restaurants, restaurants have geopoints. Query dishes sorted by distance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

My app, using Parse as a backend, shows a feed of dishes from nearby restaurants. I have set up Parse so that I have two classes, Dish and Restaurant. Each Dish has a property called restaurant, which is a pointer to an `objectId` from the Restaurant class. Each Restaurant has a property called location, which is a geopoint. My goal is to run a query which returns an array of dishes, sorted by their distance.

I can't put the pieces together. I think I may need to do two queries, but I'm not sure how that would work. Here is the code I have so far:

```
PFGeoPoint *userGeoPoint = [PFGeoPoint geoPointWithLatitude:self.currentLocationLatitude longitude:self.currentLocationLongitude]; 

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Dish"]; 

[query whereKey:@"restaurant.location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint]; 

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *dishes, NSError *error){ 
    if (error) { 
        // The query failed 
        NSLog(@"error in geo query!"); 
    } else { 
        // The query is successful 
        NSLog(@"Here are the dishes from my query:"); 
        NSLog(@"%@", dishes); 
    } 
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are correct that you'll need two queries, because you cannot do `whereKey:@"restaurant.location"`.

I would first query the Restaurant class with `whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint`, to get an array of nearby Restaurant PFObjects (say, `myRestaurants`), then use a second query on the Dish class: `query whereKey:@"restaurant" containedIn:myRestaurants` to get the dishes of those restaurants.